# Theorem 8.14 in Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis"

Tags: analysis, trigonometric-series

I am reading Rudin's "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" and I am stuck at the following theorem:

> Theorem 8.14:
> If, for some $x$, there are constants $\delta > 0$ and $M < \infty$ such that: $\left| f(x + t) - f(x) \right| \leq M|t|$ for all $t \in (-\delta, \delta)$, then $\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} s_N(f; x) = f(x)$.

A few Definitions that needed:

Dirichlet kernel: $$D_N(x) = \sum_{n=-N}^Ne^{inx} = \frac{\sin\left( (N+\frac12)x \right)}{\sin(x/2)} \qquad (77)$$
and
$$s_N(f; x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x - t) D_N(t) dt\qquad (78)$$

**The proof goes as follows:**
Define $g(t) = \frac{f(x-t) - f(x)}{\sin(t/2)}$ for $0 < |t| \leq \pi$, and put $g(0) = 0)$. By the definition (77), $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}D_N(x) dx = 1$. Hence (78) shows that:
$$
\begin{aligned}
s_N(f; x) - f(x) &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} g(t) \sin((N +\frac12)t)\\
& = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left[ g(t)\cos\frac{t}2 \right]\sin(Nt) \space dt + \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \left[ g(t)\sin\frac{t}2 \right]\cos(Nt) \space dt.
\end{aligned}
$$

$g(t)\cos(t/2)$ and $g(t)\sin(t/2)$ are bounded. The last two integrals thus tend to $0$ as $N \rightarrow \infty$.

Can anyone explain why they tend to $0$?

Comment: If $N$ is really big, $[g(t) \sin(t/2)]$ is approximately constant on each period of $\sin(Nt)$ and $\cos(Nt)$.

Comment: Riemann Lebesgue lemma

Comment: Rudin sends you to Theorem 8.12. Do you recognise its relevance?

Comment: @uniquesolution No, I don't. Can you please explain that?

Comment: @Conrad this theorem appears in chapter 8, I do not know Lebesgue lemma, I think it is in chapter 11, though indeed there is something else to prove that.

Comment: I do not have the book at hand but the claim above is that the fourier coefficients of an integrable function go to zero; Rudin may have this stated for bounded functions or there may be another equivalence there but that is what supports the claim

Comment: @Conrad Why the claim is that? Rudin stated something like that for Fourier coefficients but how does that apply here?

Comment: What is the definition of the Fourier  sine and cosine coefficients? See then what you get for the function $h(t)=g(t) \cos t/2$ and then for the function $g(t)\sin t /2$

Comment: related, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116128/finding-limit-under-integral?noredirect=1

Answer (score -1):

Since $f$ is bounded, for all $t\in (-\pi,\pi)$, there exists $M_1<\infty$ such that
$|f(x-t)-f(x)|<M_1|t|<M_1\pi$,
that is, $|g(t)\;\sin(t/2)|<M_1\pi$.
That is $g(t)\;\sin(t/2)$ is bounded.

Analogously there is $M_2<\infty$ such that $|g(t)\;\cos(t/2)|<M_2\pi$.
That is, $g(t)\;\cos(t/2)$ is bounded.

By Equation (74),$S_N(f;x)$ converges as $N\to\infty$.
Thus, the integrals on the right exist as $N\to\infty$.

Then, choosing $M=max(M_1,M_2)$, we get $\int_{-\pi}^\pi{[g(t) \;\cos(t/2)]\;\sin (Nt) dt}$

$\le M\delta\int_{-\pi}^\pi{\sin (Nt) dt}=0$ as $N\to\infty$.

Analogously we can show that $\int_{-\pi}^\pi{[g(t)\;\sin(t/2)] \cos (Nt) dt}=0$ as $N\to\infty$.

Comment: -1: the estimates in this answer make no sense, as $\sin Nt $ and $\cos Nt $ are not positive.